# Удвоенная Н в слове "растеряННо"

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

В каких случаях надо писать "растеряНо", а в каких - "растеряННо"? Что-то я никак не могу разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы решить, надо писать Н или НН,  определяем часть речи. В наречии пишется столько Н, сколько в слове, от которого оно образовано. В кратком прилагательном - столько Н, сколько в полном, в кратком причастии - одна Н.

**Всё** упущено, **растеряно** (т.е. все упустили. растеряли, значение действия) - **краткое причастие, пишу Н.**

**Лицо** мамы было **растерянно** - **краткое прилагательное** (лицо каково?, его не теряли в прямом смысле, значение качества), **пишу НН, так как в полной форме две НН** (есть приставка)

**Смотрел растерянно** (как?) - **наречие. пишу столько НН, сколько в слове. от которого образовано.** Растерянный - две НН (есть приставка)

Answer (score 0):

Если это краткое прилагательное, то одно Н, если наречие, то два: *смотреть (как?) растерянно; все имущество ратеряно.*

Comment: В вашем примере (имущество растеряно) - слово растеряно - причастие.

Comment: Спасибо, Ларf.

Answer (score 0):

У наречий пишется столько же Н, сколько было у слова, от которого это наречие образовано.

Comment: Но не всегда растерян(нн)о - наречие.